# C++ Loading files based on text fiel

Tags: c++

I am wondering if it is possible to load files based on the contents of a text file. Basically, I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
"File1.txt"
"File2.txt"
"File3.txt"
...
...
...
```

Theoretically, I could load an indefinite number of files of any type, not just .txt. I have a basic knowledge of how file loading works, but if anyone has any ideas or preferably examples of how to do this, I would be greatly thankful.

Thank you

EDIT:
It seems there is some confusion on what I am asking, so here goes nothing.

What I would like to be able to do is have the program load multiple files based on a list of file names in a text document. The file names will be names of 3d models, sound files, images, other text documents, etc. I want the program to open the text document then grab the file names line by line and somehow enter those names into a function to be loaded.

So the flow of the process would look like this:
Open text document -> Get the first file name in the text document -> Insert that file name into a function to load a file with that name -> Get the next file name in the text document -> Insert that file name into a function to load a file with that name -> etc. etc. etc.

As of right now, the only preventing me from implementing this is that I don't know how to (and have been unable to find information on how to) read the text file line by line to get the file name, and then have the program insert those names into functions for those files to be loaded, so I'm looking for some suggestion and example code if there is any. I hope this clarifies my question. If you need any more information, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Short answer is, "yes". Are you looking for code? Or do you have code that doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get an answer to your question, you should be a little more specific, like what you mean by "loading a file". Also, it helps if you show us what you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean. You have a txt file that contains file names? And from all those files you want to load only those that have specific content?

If yes, then you might like to have "tags" that belong to each file name, so you can look up easily what the content in those files is and read only those files.

Otherwise, you might have to read all files, find the correct content, and re-process the files. That would be very ineffective though.

Comment: You have the right idea, but i guess I didn't explain it real well. The idea is that I will have a text file that contains the names of other files. From that, I want to be able to load the files who's names are in the text file for use in the program. If it helps at all, what I'm trying to do is create a game engine that uses a text file to locate and load assets such as 3d models, textures, and sounds to be used in the game. Hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: @DasIsGoot What is stopping you from implementing this? I am tying to understand the reason for the question and what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string fileName;

  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,fileName) )
    {
      ifstream myfile2 (fileName);
      //do something
      myfile2.close();
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```